# Memgraph 1.6.0 returns error "does not match the detected host platform" on Docker run when using Apple M1

Tags: memgraphdb

I inherited a Memgrpah 1.6.0 based project. When I try to run the docker on my M1 power Apple I get the following error message:

```
m1lap ~> docker run -p 7687:7687 memgraph/memgraph
WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the 
detected host platform (Linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
You are running Memgraph v1.6.0-community
```

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker support for running Memgraph on Apple M1 machines was [added in Memgraph 2.2](https://memgraph.com/docs/memgraph/changelog#v220---feb-18-2022). You will need to obtain Memgraph 2.2 (or newer) and transfer your data from existing Memgraph 1.6.